# Should I simply add an image to someone elses answer?

Tags: discussion

I am unsure how I should proceed in this particular situation: Someone else has given a good answer in my opinion but I could add an image to give some more detail.

I am especially referring to this post: [Is this subscription billing mail from Apple genuine?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422461/is-this-subscription-billing-mail-from-apple-genuine)

I could add an image that shows how legitimate purchase emails from the AppStore look like, but it is in German.

Should I simply go ahead and modify this answer or add a second answer with that image (but my answer would most likely either be just a repetition or a *very* short one)?

Comment: Both is fine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost always preferable to edit a good answer with a substantial edit and this seems to meet that criteria.

Edits bump and reward people for starting an answer, they are logged and easily improved or rolled back as needed. Only if the person asks to have a new answer would a second one be worth it.

Comment: And in case somebody reverts it, then post it as a new answer and let the community judge (this happened with me - I edited an answer that and the changes were reverted. Instead of picking up an argument, I reposted it [as a new answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410739/333666).)